# Unable to delete specific sites from Safari History

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

I'm unable to delete the two links (sites) from my Safari History - `Apple Support` which is actually a malicious URL. `Right-click --> delete` doesn't work for those 2 sites alone. `Delete` works for all other sites though.

Could someone help me work out how to manually remove those?

[image]

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: I'd try [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/pricing/mac/) for starters.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately, it didn't help